# Changing Silverlight Application name dynamically

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob, out-of-browser

I'm creating a deployable module where some parts are written in Silverlight, and I'm making the SL application deployable for OOB usage. However, I want to make Silverlight take the name of the website that it's deployed from, such as, when a user installs it from Example.com, I want to have *"example.com application"* with the site's own icon in the shortcut. Is there any "supported" method of doing this, or will I be going with locating the XAP file and manually changing `AppManifest.xaml` inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to find out your URL of your application:

```
string appURL = Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0, Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(@"ClientBin/"));
```

So this will solve the title problem, next is the icon. You could load the image from the page:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("{0}/favicon.png", appURL));
IconImage.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

It's not perfect, you will have to manipulate `appURL` to get the domain name only.

Comment: I was talking about the icon on desktop/start menu when you install the app. Will this be effective for that?

Comment: when you first start your app, you start it from web and then install it to the desktop or am I wrong?

Comment: yes, but will this code work for installing on desktop? it doesn't/cannot alter the original XAP file anyway.

Comment: hmm, XAP is a zip file, try to change it's content somehow from the webpage before serving it.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'll be doing, but I was wondering if there was a non hacky better way.